# datatables jquery, base64 strings

Tags: jquery, base64, datatables, decoding

I'm getting a json from external datasource with all strings (values) encoded using base64url (using A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,_ characters). Is there a way to decode those strings on client side, so that they would display fine? Probably I need to hook the function in datatables that parses json, but how?

Here's example json:

```
"aaData": [
[
  "dGVzdDEy",
  "Zm9v"
],
...
]
```

Comment: Do you have a client side function that can decode those strings?

Comment: Yes, i've got a js function that can decode those strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most major browsers support the almost-standardised base64 encoding and decoding functions, `atob` (decode) and `btoa` (encode):

```
atob("dGVzdDEy");
// -> test12
```

However, as I said, these functions are non-standard and you will have to implement your own function (or one on the ol' sextuple-u―[like this one](https://gist.github.com/sevir/3946819)) to decode in some browsers, such as IE 9 and lower.

As for the JSON question, you can pass a *reviver* function as the second argument to JSON.parse, which will be executed for each field:

```
JSON.parse('{"aaData":[["dGVzdDEy","Zm9v"]]}', function (k, v) { 
    if (typeof(v) == "string") 
        return atob(v); 
    else 
        return v;
});
/* -> {
    "aaData": [
        [
            "test12",
            "foo"
        ]
    ]
} */
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I force datatables to parse json this way? I've just found out that I could probably use fnRowCallback event (http://datatables.net/usage/callbacks) or maybe fnServerData (not sure how though).

Comment: @MikeOwen: I'm not sure, I don't have any experience with that jQuery plugin.